# camel - quartz2 endpoint - Multiple consumers for the same endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

I am using apache camel and wants to have multiple routes.The route is as below.

1. `endpoint -> quartz2://tsTimer?cron=0%2F20+*+8-18+%3F+*+MON%2CTUE%2CWED%2CTHU%2CFRI+*&stateful=true&trigger.timeZone=Asia%2FSingapore`
2. Call bean method to get data.
3. Send to MQ

In this case my route is going to be same as the polling interval is same. 
The data from bean method will be different. 
And the MQ queue will be same.

`Failed to start route route2 because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed: quartz2://tsTimer?cron=0%2F20+*+8-18+%3F+*+MON%2CTUE%2CWED%2CTHU%2CFRI+*&stateful=true&trigger.timeZone=Asia%2FSingapore`

How do i achieve this? How do i differentiate camel route in case when the endpoint is quartz2 timer?

Answer (score 1):

I din't notice that in endpoint uri I was having `tsTimer` which will distinguishes other end-points.

Something like below

```
quartz2://tsTimer1
quartz2://tsTimer2
quartz2://tsTimer3
```